# git how to merge and choose which files I want from which branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have

```
branch 1 
-file A
-file B
-file C
branch 2
-file A
-file B
-file C
```

I would like to merge branch 1 and 2, so that in the resulting branch file A would be from branch 1, file C would be from branch 2. file B would be a manual merge by me, I would like to take some part from branch 1 and some from branch 2. 
I know that to merge I can do

```
git checkout b1
git merge b2
git commit -b1
```

but it would auto merge file A and C, how do I make sure I can take different versions from branches I specify. The real problem involves more files for me so if you can explain how to take multiple files in the answer commands that would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This goes against the grain for git. Git's unit of storage is a commit, not a file. Are there any alternatives based on commits? Cherry-picking is more usual approach to partial merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** test this on a testing repo and then make a backup of you repo before doing this

First checkout to a new branch from branch1 lets call it 'final-branch'

> git checkout -b final-branch branch1

Now we will get the fileC from branch2

> git checkout branch2 -- fileC.txt

Now you will have fileA from branch1 and fileC from branch2

now we can commit these changes and at the end fileA will have changes from branch1 and fileC will have changes from branch2

> git add fileC.txt
>
> git commit -m "final-commit"

if you want to checkout multiple files from branch2

> git checkout branch2 -- file1 file2 file3 file4

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout b1
git merge -n -s ours b2     # set merged parent to b2 but start with purely b1 content
git checkout -p b2:fileB    # select b2 hunks from b2's fileB
git checkout b2:fileC       # take all of b2's fileC
git commit                  # parents and content set properly, make the commit.
```

Note that you're not required to take your merge result content from anywhere in particular, you can set merged results to anything that makes sense in your workflow.  Just be aware that the farther you stray from the ~usual~ style of workflow the convenience tools are set up to facilitate, the farther from useful their later results will stray.  When you make a merge commit, Git presumes that the result is a correct and complete merge of the parent histories.  It's not the only possible such merge, you can make other merges of the same parents and achieve useful combined-arms effects by merging the different merges of the same parents.